# Call compound.finance api with parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to simply call the compound.finance api "https://api.compound.finance/api/v2/account" with the parameter max_health. the doc says

> "If provided, should be given as { "value": "...string formatted
> number..." }".

(https://compound.finance/docs/api#account-service)

So I tried 4 methods here below:

```
response = requests.get(
    'https://api.compound.finance/api/v2/account',
    params={
        "max_health": "1.0" # method 1
        "max_health": {"value":"1.0"} # method 2
        "max_health": json.dumps({"value":"1.0"}) # method 3
    }
)
```

but it does not work, and I get

> HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url:...

Any idea I should format it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They did not update the API docs. You should send a POST request and provide params as a request body.

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://api.compound.finance/api/v2/account"
data = {
    "max_health": {"value": "1.0"}
}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))  # <Response [200]>
response = response.json()  # {'accounts': ...}
```

##### *Edit notes*

The problem was that the API expects raw JSON so I used `json.dumps`.

Comment: Indeed, it does not throw any error. However, when inspecting the response: 'request': {'addresses': [],
  'block_number': 0,
  'block_timestamp': 0,
  'max_health': None,
  'min_borrow_value_in_eth': None,
  'network': 'mainnet',
  'page_number': 1,
  'page_size': 10}. Seems like max_health has not been passed. And indeed, it did not filter anything

Comment: I am not the owner of the API and do not know how it should respond. I tried with values 1.0 and 10.0 and then compared the last parts of the responses, which were different.

Comment: I tried with 1.0 and 10 too, and yields the same results. Try runnng the two one right after the other. Maybe you wanted and got the result from the block after

Comment: @NicolasRey, please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Artyom already explained his beautiful answer, indeed their API documentation unfortunately outdated. In addition to his answer I'd like to add that `requests` library supports `json` argument that accepts raw JSON arguments starting with `requests` version `2.4.2`. Therefore `data=json.dumps(params)` is not necessary anymore.

See my code below.

```
api_base = "https://api.compound.finance/api/v2/account"
params = {'max_health': {'value':'0.95'},
          'min_borrow_value_in_eth': { 'value': '0.002' },
          'page_number':19,
         }
response = requests.post(api_base, json=params).json()
```